# PowerShell Script to audit VMs disk information

Tags: azure

As part of the storage cost optimization, we need to extract the following information from Azure at the disk level for migrated servers so far.

Please suggest if any one have a PowerShell script.

I could only get the provisioned storage, but not the used storage.

1. VM name.
2. Disk name (maybe more than one).
3. Provisioned storage.
4. Used storage.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take the time to read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in order to understand how to post a good question so that the community can assist you. Please edit your post and add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have already implemented and any errors or logs you might get.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with log analytics, if you connect the VMs to a Log Analytics Workspace and enable Guest OS Metrics / Performance Counters and then query the Log Analytics Workspace.

Here is a script to get you started:

```
Perf
| where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "% Free Space"
| summarize FreeSpace = min(CounterValue) by Computer, InstanceName
| where strlen(InstanceName) ==2 and InstanceName contains ":"
| sort by CounterName asc
```